# Ace Editor multi auto completions

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, requirejs, ace-editor

I have a code like this: http://jsfiddle.net/s74BV/
I want `html, css, javascript and php` to be validated and autocompleted.
In the jsFiddle you can see that this is working good enough for `html, css and javascript` but php is not working correctly. I think it is because of the html mode that I put the ace editor in, but I can't figure out how to use multiple modes and autocompletes at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want autocompletions for php, set editor mode to "ace/mode/php".
As for validation, Ace doesn't support validation for nested modes.

Comment: I want all of them to autocomplete, not just 1, or 3 out of 4.